# Side bar size is reduced

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, sidebar

In the side bar after receiving this **Welcoming Stack Overflow’s New CMO – Adrianna Burrows** blog item, the size of the side bar is reduced.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Side bar]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's now fixed and will be live on production really soon :).

Comment: I didn't expect that **that** _soon_.

Comment: Is this due to the puzzling new design role out?

Comment: @Arulkumar No, this is due to me not having enough coffee